# Rails installing a Gem - hostname does not match the server certificate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, rubygems, certificate

I've recently been trying to work with Amazon EC2 to upload my first Rails project. In that process I vaguely remember configuring a key somewhere in the command line to let me connect to the EC2 instance. Anyway, since that (I think), I'm unable to install Ruby Gems as I get the error:

[image]

I've been looking for hours to try and fix this with no joy so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your gem config is still looking at `https://gemcutter.org`.

Visiting this in your browser you will quickly realise the problem, the SSL certificate is signed for `rubygems.org`

I suggest you change your gem source to `https://rubygems.org`

Try setting the gem source

```
gem sources --add https://rubygems.org/
```

Now if you run

```
gem sources
```

you should get something like

```
*** CURRENT SOURCES ***

https://gemcutter.org/
https://rubygems.org/
```

So remove gemcutter.org too

```
gem sources --remove https://gemcutter.org/
```

Then you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks very much, this fixed it! Any ideas why this happened when gems were installing properly before? Also, now I have got Rubber to install, it only has the config command... see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14522051/rails-rubber-gem-no-such-sub-command-vulcanize/14536914#14536914

Comment: I think it's due to the recent problems with rubygems.org, they probably didn't realise they'd broken gemcutter.org's SSL cert.

Comment: looking at it again, now `https://gemcutter.org` redirects to `https://rubygems.org`